# Targeting an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a value in this format:

```
var state = [{"industry-type":"football","your-role":"coach"}]
```

I would like to output "football". How can I do this?

I've tried `state[0].industry-type` but it returns an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What you have is an array of object(s), not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

It does not like the '-' in your property name, try:

```
state[0]['industry-type']
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you can't access a property with `-` directly.

```js
var state = [{"industry-type":"football","your-role":"coach"}];

console.log(state[0]['industry-type']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-` symbol is reserved in Javascript, you cannot use it to refer to an object's property because Javascript thinks you're trying to do subtraction: `state[0].industry - type;` Hence the error "*Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined*" - it is looking for a variable named `type` to subtract with, which it can't find.

Instead, refer to it by:

```
state[0]['industry-type']
```

Because in Javascript, `object.property` and `object['property']` are equal.

---

For what it's worth, if you have control over those names, it is best practice in Javascript to name things with [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), so your variable would be defined as:

```
var state = [{"industryType":"football","yourRole":"coach"}]
```

Then, you could access it like:

```
state[0].industryType
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to use dot notation then your:

> ...property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of
>   alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and
>   dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Like the other answers pointed out, you have to use square bracket notation to access property names of an object that are not valid JavaScript identifiers.

e.g.

```
state[0]["industry-type"]
```

Related SO question:

[What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use bracket notation for the attribute -

`state[0]['industry-type']`